# Qt Creator + CMake + custom compiler

Tags: cmake, g++, qt-creator

I've been struggling with Qt Creator to set up a different compiler (g++-5) instead of the stock compiler (4.8.5).

In spite of my best efforts to tie everything, I seem to be missing a key ingredient to bind everything together.

[image: Compiler setup]

[image: Kit setup]

[image: CMake configuration]

If I try to change the compiler manually, I get this dialog below which asks me if I want the IDE to undo or ignore what I've done.

[image: Changes]

Shouldn't be that difficult. So, what have I missed? 
Thanks && regards

Comment: From experience Qt is bad at managing update, try to suppress the CMakeLists.txt.user and your build dir, then reopen qtcreator select your kit with gcc-5 and it should works otherwise it keeps stuck with previous variable cache etc... When you select "Projects" in the Mode Selector you can see the list of kit in use be sure to match the good one

Comment: actually, I stumbled over a similar solution. Went to the build directory, erased all cmake info (rm -r *) and then restarted the IDE. Must do for every new build configuration.